# Using Ajax for maincontentText in Highslide (in Highcharts)

Tags: highcharts, highslide

First, thanks for the help!

Basically, I'm using Highslide in Highcharts to display some pictures when someone clicks on a datapoint in a line graph. Below is the code:

```
hs.htmlExpand(null, 
                {                       
                    pageOrigin: 
                    {
                        x: this.pageX,
                        y: this.pageY
                    },

                    headingText: "<p style='margin: 0 auto;'> Weight: " + this.y,

                    maincontentText: "<p class='pictures'></p>" +
                        $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "pictures.php",
                    data: 
                    {
                        "date" : this.Pictures
                    },
                    success: function(result)
                    {
                        $('.pictures').html(result); 
                    }
                }),

                    width: 700, 

                    height: 600
                });
```

Right now, Highslide correctly displays the pictures, but it also outputs "[Object object]" at the end of the Highslide pop-out. If I change my php page to just "echo 'test';", it displays the word "test" and then the [Object object].

Any ideas on how to get rid of this [Object object] piece?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax appears to be returning a json object.  You will need to parse that object to format the result you want to display, or return HTML instead...

Edit::

on second thought, it seems more like an issue with how your are specifying the main content.

Using the + at the end of your HTML for the main content, you are including the ajax call as content.

I would specify the html element in your maincontent, but remove the ajax to a onAfterExpand call instead.

http://highslide.com/ref/hs.Expander.prototype.onAfterExpand

Comment: I tried using dataType: 'html', but it still results in the [object Object] at the end of the pop-out. My php page is outputting HTML (three pictures and some paragraphs). Anything else I should try?

Comment: [object Object] means that the data being returned is an object.  You are then populating your paragraph with that object.  You will have to parse the object in order to retrieve the content.  Try doing a console.log on the object you return - in the console you will then be able to see the contents of the object, and the keys by which to access it.

Comment: The plot thickens...I changed out the php page so that it just outputs "this is a test" using an echo. Now, in my popout, I get "this is a test" followed by "[object Object]" on a new line. When I do console.log to output the result from the ajax above, it just gives me the line "this is a test" - it doesn't recognize any other output that might be interpreted as JSON data.

I should also note that if I replace the whole ajax bit above in the maincontentText piece with "test", it outputs "test" in the popout without the [object Object]...so I think it has to do with the Ajax

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I couldn't use this solution until I saw your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820031/highcharts-chart-inside-of-a-highslide-popout) because the usage of **onAfterExpand** is unclear and unusual for me.
So I found another working combination of Ajax, Highcharts and Highslide :)
Something like this inside plotOptions.spline.point.events:

```
click: function (e) {
    var curobj = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/path/to/test.html",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data){
            hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                pageOrigin: {
                    x: e.pageX || e.clientX,
                    y: e.pageY || e.clientY
                },
                headingText: curobj.series.name,
                maincontentText: data,
                width: 300
            });
        }

    });
}
```